# How to sort Sqlite results in android?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am fetching records from a database. I need the last record to display first and so on. Below is the query I am using. Could someone help me to create the correct query.

```
public Cursor fetchAllRec() {
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = null;
    cur = db.query(TBL_NAME, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.moveToFirst();
    }

    return cur;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of the [query method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) allows you to sort the results.